# Changing the picker view AM/PM into chinese

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app i'm using the time picker for setting the time.It is working fine.But when i am changing the region format into chinese the picker view is changing but the i cant roll the minute bar.How to slve this issue.please help.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the bug fixed.
The problem was with the IBOutlet.When we shrink the size of picker the rolling bar of hour will not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set US(or any other with "AM/PM" time format) locale explicitly to `UIDatePicker`'s `locale` property?

Comment: @Andry.i got it.I changed the region format.i edited my question.please help me.

Comment: @ishhh Sorry, but I don't understand what is the problem: appearance or behavior?

Comment: @ Andry,In this case rolling bar for hour is not working.i can change the minutes bar,AM/PM but can'y change hour.